# How to DRAG/ MOVE a RelativeLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am zooming a `relative layout`, but after zooming i am unable to drag or move the `zoomed layout`
this is my code to zoom the layout..plz help me to drag or move the `zoomed layout`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

View mainView = null;
// Remember some things for zooming
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();

float oldDist = 1f;
PointF oldDistPoint = new PointF();

public static String TAG = "ZOOM";

static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    mainView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
            int DRAGUP;
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                mode = DRAG;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                oldDistPoint = spacingPoint(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                }
                System.out.println("current time :"
                        + System.currentTimeMillis());
                break;// return !gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                mode = DRAG;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {

                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    PointF newDist = spacingPoint(event);
                    float newD = spacing(event);
                    Log.e(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                    float[] old = new float[9];
                    float[] newm = new float[9];
                    Log.e(TAG, "x=" + old[0] + ":&:" + old[2]);
                    Log.e(TAG, "y=" + old[4] + ":&:" + old[5]);
                    float scale = newD / oldDist;
                    float scalex = newDist.x / oldDistPoint.x;
                    float scaley = newDist.y / oldDistPoint.y;
                    zoom(scale, scale, start);
                }
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

/**
 * zooming is done from here
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void zoom(Float scaleX, Float scaleY, PointF pivot) {
    mainView.setPivotX(pivot.x);
    mainView.setPivotY(pivot.y);
    mainView.setScaleX(scaleX);
    mainView.setScaleY(scaleY);
}

/**
 * space between the first two fingers
 */
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    // ...
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

private PointF spacingPoint(MotionEvent event) {
    PointF f = new PointF();
    f.x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    f.y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return f;
}

/**
 * the mid point of the first two fingers
 */
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    // ...
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}
}
```

So please let me know what is that i am to add in the `mode == DRAG` block..

ThankYou.

Answer (score 0):

Your setOnTouchListener code is in onCreate which gets called only once. You may need to check onConfigurationChanged or onPaint events. i have not used zoom so can only give you the hint.